# How to to copy Flow type of properties from another React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am creating a component that wraps another component called `Button`. `Button` is defined in library that does not export type of `Button`'s properties.

To correctly type my component, it would be ideal to copy the type of `Button`'s properties, add a few properties to that type (using `typeof`, `$Diff` or alike) and use it as type of my component `StyledButton`.

Something like:

```
type AddedPropsT = {
  isStyled: boolean,
}

function StyledButton(props: $GenericParam(typeof Button) & AddedPropsType) {
  return (<Button ...props className={isStyled ? "StyleClass" : ""} />)
}
```

Of course type util `$GenericParam` does not exist in Flow. The type of `Button` is  [`React.ComponentType<Props>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype) (the question is how do I get that `Props` type from there) and behind the scenes it is pure function stateless component.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to extract a generic parameter. Seems like it'd be super useful. Created this: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6895

Comment: @Jacob Thanks Jacob, wasn't sure, I am new to Flow. Right it would be super usefull so thanks for creating issue. Hope it will get noticed soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`React.ElementConfig<typeof Component>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-elementconfig) utility type to get Button's props type:

```
type AddedProps = {
  isStyled: boolean,
}

function StyledButton(props: React.ElementConfig<typeof Button> & AddedProps) {
  return (<Button {...props} className={props.isStyled ? "StyleClass" : ""} />)
}
```